# Installation error creating table tuserremotesessions

Tags: mysql, coldfusion-11, mura

Installing Mura on a brand new machine and local MySQL 5.7 database. Per the install instructions I browse to the Mura index.cfm file to complete the installation. I enter in the database and DSN info. After a few seconds I get an error message.

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> Datasource: muracms
>
> SQL: CREATE TABLE
>   IF NOT EXISTS `tuserremotesessions` ( `userID` char(35) default NULL,
>   `authToken` char(32) default NULL, `data` text, `created` datetime
>   default NULL, `lastAccessed` datetime default NULL, PRIMARY KEY
>   (`userID`) )
>
> Code: 42000
>
> Type: 42000
>
> All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Refreshing browser page results in this error again. I can see that tables have already been created in the database. I have been unsuccessful at attempts to internet search for a solution.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to get past this error? I have successfully installed Mura on other servers before so I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into this error, it is due to a change in MySql 5.7 from how MySql 5.6 worked. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html. Specifically

> Columns in a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL, but if declared explicitly
>   as NULL produced no error. Now an error occurs. For example, a
>   statement such as CREATE TABLE t (i INT NULL PRIMARY KEY) is rejected.

I edited the create table statements for several tables in {murahome}/requirements/mura/dbUpdates/5.2.0.cfm to remove the `default NULL` statement on two tables and then everything worked fine.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Thanks for sharing your findings. In the future, please feel free to submit a ticket on our project at https://github.com/blueriver/MuraCMS/issues

Cheers, Steve